# XSLT Recursion Output

Tags: xslt

I have been searching a lot on this forum, so as to avoid the posting the question.

My input XML looks something like this :

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <table>
    <tag id="segment" name="a">
       <data>segment1</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="b">
       <data>data1</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="c">
       <data>data2</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="segment" name="d">
       <data>segment2</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="e">
       <data>data3</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="f">
       <data>data4</data>
    </tag>
</table>
```

---

I want to output the data something like this :

segment1-data1

segment1-data2

segment2-data3

segment2-data4

I tried with a recursive XSLT but that seem to work as intended.
Any ideas about how could I get this ?
Thanks !

Comment: can you post what you have so far?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very straightforward issue for XSLT 2.0 grouping because of the matching going on in group-starting-with=.

```
t:\ftemp>type segments.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <table>
    <tag id="segment" name="a">
       <data>segment1</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="b">
       <data>data1</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="c">
       <data>data2</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="segment" name="d">
       <data>segment2</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="e">
       <data>data3</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="f">
       <data>data4</data>
    </tag>
</table>
t:\ftemp>xslt2 segments.xml segments.xsl
segment1-data1
segment1-data2
segment2-data3
segment2-data4

t:\ftemp>type segments.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="tag" group-starting-with="tag[@id='segment']">
    <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="data"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[position()>1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix,'-',data)"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, then this is an answer for you ... note that recursion is not necessary, you just need to address the items you want from the tree:

```
t:\ftemp>type segments.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <table>
    <tag id="segment" name="a">
       <data>segment1</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="b">
       <data>data1</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="c">
       <data>data2</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="segment" name="d">
       <data>segment2</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="e">
       <data>data3</data>
    </tag>
    <tag id="data" name="f">
       <data>data4</data>
    </tag>
</table>
t:\ftemp>xslt segments.xml segments1.xsl
segment1-data1
segment1-data2
segment2-data3
segment2-data4

t:\ftemp>type segments1.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:for-each select="tag[@id='segment']">
    <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="data"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::tag[@id='data']
                       [generate-id(preceding-sibling::tag[@id='segment'][1])=
                        generate-id(current())]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix,'-',data)"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>
```